# Laravel: split one cluttered method into several methods

Tags: php, laravel, refactoring

In a Laravel app, I have a method `modalDelete` that checks several things.

When a condition is not fulfilled, a modal view is returned with the appropriate error message and execution stops.

If all conditions are fulfilled, the same modal is returned showing the form for confirming deletion:

```
public function modalDelete(...$params)
{
    // get the last element of $params: it's our id
    $id = end($params);

    // check that page is called via AJAX
    if (session('_token') !== request()->header('X-CSRF-TOKEN')) {
        return abort(403, 'Unauthorized');
    }

    // check that model exists
    try {
        $record = $this->model->findOrFail($id);
    } catch (ModelNotFoundException $e) {
        return view('_partials.modals.delete')->with('error', 'Record not found');
    }

    // additional check for User model
    if ($this->model instanceof User) {

        // can't delete the first user
        if ($record->id === 1) { //
            return view('_partials.modals.delete')->with('error', 'You can not delete Admin');
        }

        // can't delete himself
        $user = Auth::user();
        if ($record->id === $user->id) { //
            return view('_partials.modals.delete')->with('error', 'You can not delete yourself');
        }
    }

    $route = route(str_replace('.delete', '.destroy', Route::currentRouteName()), $params);

    return view('_partials.modals.delete', compact('route'));
}
```

So far so good, this is perfectly working.

But I'd like to remove the clutter from this method, and extract each `if` or `try...catch` in its own method, to get a more modular approach:

```
public function delete(...$params)
{
    // get the last element of $params: it's our id
    $id = end($params);

    $this->checkToken();
    $record = $this->checkModel($id);
    $this->checkUser($record);
    ...
}

public function checkToken()
{
    if (session('_token') !== request()->header('X-CSRF-TOKEN')) {
        return abort(403, 'Unauthorized');
    }
    return true;
}

public function checkModel($id)
{
    try {
        $record = $this->model->findOrFail($id);
    } catch (ModelNotFoundException $e) {
        return view('_partials.modals.delete')->with('error', 'Record not found');
    }
    return $record;
}

public function checkUser($record)
{
    $id = $record->id;
    if ($this->model instanceof User) {
        $this->checkAdmin($id);
        $this->checkSelf($id);
    }    
}

public function checkAdmin($id)
{
    if ($id === 1) { //
        return view('_partials.modals.delete')->with('error', 'You can not delete Admin');
    }
    return true;
}

...
```

Well, this doesn't work (except the `checkToken()` method): I end up with confirmation form even if the user should be stopped long before because one of the conditions is not met.

I'm almost sure that the problem lies in the `return` statements of each method, but I have no idea how to write the right code

Any help, please?

Comment: Your return statements in newly formed methods are returned to delete method only that's the reason behind the problem

Comment: Uhm... I didn't get it, please can you elaborate?

Comment: Since you have break a large function to a group of smaller functions, when you return something from those smaller functions then you are just returned to your delete function from where these smaller functions are being called. For working case you should return from main delete function as well. This is what I mean :D

Answer (score 0):

Splitting it up into nice small methods is a better approach than the first method. But what you really should be doing is using the power of Laravel and all its little helpful features.

Here are some examples

```
// check that page is called via AJAX
if (session('_token') !== request()->header('X-CSRF-TOKEN')) {
    return abort(403, 'Unauthorized');
}
```

The code above shoud be in a middleware  https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/middleware

The next part of your code is validation so you should use validation for that https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#form-request-validation

```
// check that model exists
try {
    $record = $this->model->findOrFail($id);
} catch (ModelNotFoundException $e) {
    return view('_partials.modals.delete')->with('error', 'Record not found');
}

// additional check for User model
if ($this->model instanceof User) {

    // can't delete the first user
    if ($record->id === 1) { //
        return view('_partials.modals.delete')->with('error', 'You can not delete Admin');
    }

    // can't delete himself
    $user = Auth::user();
    if ($record->id === $user->id) { //
        return view('_partials.modals.delete')->with('error', 'You can not delete yourself');
    }
}
```

Then all you are left with is the following

```
public function modalDelete(...$params)
{
    $route = route(str_replace('.delete', '.destroy',     Route::currentRouteName()), $params);
    return view('_partials.modals.delete', compact('route'));
}
```

Comment: Thanks Maantje: it's fine to put the token verification in a middleware, but the other part is not a form validation: the user clicks a link to delete an item, and before deleting all those checks are done, to ensure data integrity... the `modalDelete()` method is a "catch-all" that I put in a Trait for re-using in every model that need deletion... in short, I'd like to keep this approach